# Theano SDE example

Tags: theano

I'm trying to work through an example on solving SDEs on GPU using Theano found [here](http://www.nehalemlabs.net/prototype/blog/2013/10/17/solving-stochastic-differential-equations-with-theano/)

I'm stuck with a GpuDimShuffle error, but I'm not seeing how any of the dims don't match...

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams import RandomStreams
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#define the ode function
#dc/dt  = f(c, lambda)
#c is a vector with n components
def evolve(c, n, k, l):
    return T.pow(c, n)/(T.pow(c, n)+T.pow(k,n)) - l*c

def euler(c, n, k, l, dt):
    return T.cast(c + dt*evolve(c, n, k, l) + T.sqrt(dt)*c*rv_n, 'float32')

def rk4(c, n, k, l, dt):
    '''
    Adapted from
    http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/stochastic_rk/stochastic_rk.html
    '''
    a21 =   2.71644396264860
    a31 = - 6.95653259006152
    a32 =   0.78313689457981
    a41 =   0.0
    a42 =   0.48257353309214
    a43 =   0.26171080165848
    a51 =   0.47012396888046
    a52 =   0.36597075368373
    a53 =   0.08906615686702
    a54 =   0.07483912056879

    q1 =   2.12709852335625
    q2 =   2.73245878238737
    q3 =  11.22760917474960
    q4 =  13.36199560336697

    x1 = c
    k1 = dt * evolve(x1, n, k, l) + T.sqrt(dt) * c * rv_n

    x2 = x1 + a21 * k1
    k2 = dt * evolve(x2, n, k, l) + T.sqrt(dt) * c * rv_n

    x3 = x1 + a31 * k1 + a32 * k2
    k3 = dt * evolve(x3, n, k, l) + T.sqrt(dt) * c * rv_n

    x4 = x1 + a41 * k1 + a42 * k2
    k4 = dt * evolve(x4, n, k, l) + T.sqrt(dt) * c * rv_n

    return T.cast(x1 + a51 * k1 + a52 * k2 + a53 * k3 + a54 * k4, 'float32')

#random
srng = RandomStreams(seed=31415)

#define symbolic variables
dt = T.fscalar("dt")
k = T.fscalar("k")
l = T.fscalar("l")
n = T.fscalar("n")
c = T.fvector("c")

#define numeric variables
num_samples = 50000
c0 = theano.shared(0.5*np.ones(num_samples, dtype='float32'))
n0 = 6
k0 = 0.5
l0 = 1/(1+np.power(k0, n0))
dt0 = 0.1
total_time = 8
total_steps = int(total_time/dt0)
rv_n = srng.normal(c.shape, std=0.05) #is a shared variable

#create loop
#first symbolic loop with everything
(cout, updates) = theano.scan(fn=rk4,
                                outputs_info=[c], #output shape
                                non_sequences=[n, k, l, dt], #fixed parameters
                                n_steps=total_steps)
#compile it
sim = theano.function(inputs=[n, k, l, dt],givens={c:c0}, outputs=cout,updates=updates,allow_input_downcast=True)
```

Yielding:

TypeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Rebroadcast{0(GpuDimShuffle{x,0}.0), '\n', 'super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type')

I'm on Theano 0.6.0

Answer (score 1):

If you update to the development version, it work for me:

http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions

We try to keep the development version very stable and I recomment everybody to use it, since it contain many fixes since the last release.

If that don't fix it, the error is specific to your OS or python version. We will need more information about it. Also always provide the full error message with the traceback. This provide much more debugging information.